# Documentation for Inference from saved model in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

As explained at [Multilayer CNN for MNIST Digit Recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/pros/#build_a_multilayer_convolutional_network) I created a CNN for MNIST image recognition dataset. I don't want to test it in the same script so I trained the model, saved the checkpoint files and graph structure and then using [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) script. I froze it into one single .pb file. Now using this .pb file I want to infer for MNIST test dataset and check the accuracy of the model but there is no clear documentation as to how to do it. There is one example written in examples/label_images directory but that too is in C++ and for inception network. I have already parsed the .pb file and made a tf.Graph object. And also why can't a single inference script be provided since whole graph structure can be read from graph saved in the .pb file.